# Error with snapd. "system does not fully support snapd": cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs"

Tags: mount, snap, https, squashfs, letsencrypt

I was trying to install snap (or snapd). I used the command: sudo apt install snapd

It seemed to install successfully, but when I went to install the hello-world package from snap I got this error

```
root@Djs-vps:/tmp# snap install hello-world
error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs": mount:
       /tmp/syscheck-mountpoint-1624873077: mount failed: Operation not permitted.
```

Here is some information about my system

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

Here is some information about snap

````
root@Djs-vps:/tmp# snap --version
snap    2.58+22.04
snapd   2.58+22.04
series  16
ubuntu  22.04
kernel  5.2.0```
````

Comment: It was downloaded but it was not working properly so I tried to uninstall it and try it again. I also downloaded a few other recommended APT packages to try and get it working.

Comment: It did not. After following this article [https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/system-does-not-fully-support-snapd-cannot-mount-squashfs-image-using-squashfs/132689/2] (here) I realized that my system could not run snapd. I just downloaded certbot with apt. The problem was solved but I cant use snap. I had to use apt and download an older version.